# MSI Mystic Light music mode modifications?

Tags: windows, bios

On my Z270 SLI PLUS from MSI, it has a RGB header for a light strip. in the software (Mystic Light) there's a mode for the LEDs to react to music. this is good and all but the LEDs take about 0.25 secs to update, making the reactive LEDs pretty useless.

The reason i'm asking about this here is that i was wondering how i would go about making my own software (hopefully not) or making modifications to the existing Mystic Light software to make the updates faster.